# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException with mysql DataSource and gretty

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jndi, gretty

I am making a spring mvc application using gradle as the build tool and Mysql as the jndi datasource .I am able to run it by building a war and deploying it manually . But when i am trying to run it using gretty i am getting the following exception

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

This is my build.gradle file :-

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
//apply plugin: 'jetty' //too old, Jetty6, use gretty
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jacoco' //code coverage

def springVersion = "4.2.4.RELEASE"
def jdkVersion = 1.8
def junitVersion = "4.12"
def logbackVersion = "1.1.3"
def jclOverSlf4jVersion = "1.7.14"
def jstlVersion = "1.2"
def hamcrestVersion = "1.3"
def servletApiVersion = "3.1"
def mysqlVersion = "5.1.31"

sourceCompatibility = jdkVersion
targetCompatibility = jdkVersion

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:' + jclOverSlf4jVersion
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:' + logbackVersion
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:' +springVersion
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:' + springVersion
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:' + springVersion
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:' + jstlVersion
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-test:' + springVersion
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:' + mysqlVersion
    //exclude the build in hamcrest
    testCompile('junit:junit:' + junitVersion) {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:' + hamcrestVersion
    //include in compile only, exclude in the war
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:' + servletApiVersion

}

//Gretty
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:1.1.5'
  }
}

gretty {
  port = 9090
  contextPath = 'loanSharks'
  servletContainer = 'tomcat8'
}



//For Eclipse IDE only
eclipse {

  wtp {
    component {

      //define context path, default to project folder name
      contextPath = 'loanSharks'

    }

  }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.5+"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Here's my jndi entry in web.xml :-

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/devcore</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

This is my entry in spring-config file :-

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/devcore" /> 
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

I also have my database entries in META-INF/context.xml files and META-INF/jetty-env.xml files as it was suggested in some other related posts. So can anyone please explain why i am unable to use gretty to run my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to activate naming inside gretty configuration:

```
gretty {
  enableNaming = true
}
```